# Get the time duration from login time in Session("date_time")

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i m using Session("date_time") for storing login date and time and during the time of logout i need to store the duration of the time only and for that i m using a login_duration as integer as login_duration = (Session("date_time").ToString - Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"))... but its not working properly.. Help me plz to solve the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688242/how-to-calculate-time-between-2-date this gonna help you

Answer (score 0):

For time : `TimeValue(Now)`
For date and time : `NOW`

About the format, check [here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/date-time-functions-visual-basic)